# CakePHP 3 Password Reset

Tags: php, cakephp, passwords, cakephp-3.0, change-password

I have the following code to reset my password via a link through email (that works fine).

In my User Controller:

```php
 public function resetpw($token = null) {
        $resetpw = $this->Users->findByToken('id');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $pw = $this->request->data['password'];
            $pwtable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
            $newpw = $pwtable->find($resetpw);
            $newpw->password = $pw;
            if ($pwtable->save($newpw)) {
                 $this->Flash->success(__('Your password has been successfully updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
            else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Your password could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
             }
        }
    }
```

The Reset Password CTP file:

Resetting your password?

```
<?= $this->Flash->render(); ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your new password.') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password', ['label' => 'New Password']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('confirmpassword', ['type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Confirm New Password']) ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Update password')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I also have the following rules regarding comparing the two passwords:

```php
public function validatePasswords($validator)
{
    $validator->add('confirmpassword', 'no-misspelling', [
        'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password'],
        'message' => 'The passwords are not the same.',
    ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

After typing in two identical passwords for both the password & comfirmpassword fields, I get the following error:

> Unknown finder method "SELECT Users.id AS `Users__id`, Users.username
>   AS `Users__username`, Users.password AS `Users__password`, Users.email
>   AS `Users__email`, Users.role AS `Users__role`, Users.token AS
>   `Users__token` FROM users Users WHERE Users.token = :c0"

Comment: I think you mean `$this->Users->findByToken($token)`; I also don't know why you are searching when $this->Users first, then use TableRegister to get another instance of the Users model....

Comment: @AD7six Basically I'm trying to get the token data from the Users table to determine which user's password needs to be reset. Then getting the entered password, searching up the User table for the user's password and then overwriting it.

Comment: @JvO In the CakePHP 3 Cookbook, the method of updating data uses TableRegistry & get such as the example: `$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');` and then `$article = $articlesTable->get(12)`, where the data retrieved has the id of 12. Since I'm using a token that is generated upon finding an id and it's associated email in the database, I'm wondering what would be a way of structuring it so that it references the id of the generated token.

Comment: I know, it's Cookbook boiler plate code. But: in controller X, there's automatically a $this->X that refers to the model. So creating a new object is just wasting memory. As to finding the id: the idea is to search by token. which returns a user object and from that you fetch the id: $resetpw->id. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

### Preamble

There are many odd things in the code in the question so before continuing, some required reading:

- [The blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)
- [Retrieving Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)
- [The blog tutorial - Auth](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)
- [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html)

These sections aught to give enough information to have a code structure that logically can work. This is mentioned because of the following code in the question:

- `TableRegistry::get('ControllerName')` usage - Not necessary
- `Table->findByToken('literal-string')` - will always return the same thing (nothing)
- `$table->find($notAString);` - does not match the api of the find method

### Updating a field is just an edit

It's important to recognize that fundamentally, resetting a user's password is just an edit action. Here is an example of an edit action [taken from the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-articles):

```
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php

public function edit($id = null)
{
    $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
    }

    $this->set('article', $article);
}
```

There are the following steps:

- Find an article entity
- Update the article entity
- Save the article entity
- Some error handling

These steps are the same as are required in the question scenario. Adapting the above code to the question this code becomes:

```
// src/Controller/UsersController.php

public function edit($token = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->findByToken($token)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('No user with that token found.'));
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }

    if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
        $user->password = $this->request->data['password'];
        $user->confirmpassword = $this->request->data['confirmpassword'];
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your password has been successfully updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Your password could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

### Hashing the password?

It's not mentioned in the question but the above code expects the user entity to [hash the password when it's set](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords):

> You are responsible for hashing the passwords before they are
>   persisted to the database, the easiest way is to use a setter function
>   in your User entity:
>
> ```
> namespace App\Model\Entity;
>
> use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
> use Cake\ORM\Entity;
>
> class User extends Entity
> {
>
>     // ...
>
>     protected function _setPassword($password)
>     {
>         if (strlen($password) > 0) {
>           return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
>         }
>     }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Otherwise, the plain text password will be saved in the users table and not the hash, and login will not work.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I did hash my password earlier, but I'm still getting an issue when attempting to save the new password: `Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::save() must be an instance of Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, instance of Cake\ORM\Query given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\src\Controller\UserController on line 189`, with line 189 referring to `if ($this->Users->save($user)) {`

Comment: So I've encountered two separate issues: If I use the corrected code, and click the link in the email, I am redirected to the home page (no token found, despite a token existing in the SQL table for that user), and if I comment out the token check code (which allows me to enter a new password), I get the error: `Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::save() must be an instance of Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, instance of stdClass given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\src\Controller\UsersController.php on line 189`, with line 189 again being `if ($this->Users->save($user)) {`

Comment: Looking forward to hearing how you debug and fix those issues :) (They do not appear to be related to the code/logic in this answer, or at least are _other_ preexisting problems with your application logic).